# AWS Amplify/Cognito: Dynamically Selecting Auth Flow

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'd like to set up an authentication system in AWS Amplify with a Cognito User Pool that supports either the `USER_SRP_AUTH` or `CUSTOM_AUTH`, and have the app dynamically select between the two at the sign-in step.

The Amplify documentation for [Switching Authentication Flows](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/switch-auth/q/platform/js/) shows how you can do this by updating the global Amplify config, but is there any way to do this by just setting a single value (the authentication flow) instead of needing to store, update, and set the entire Amplify configuration each time?